# chat client with redis in c# freezes. Anyone can suggest anything?

Tags: c#, winforms, redis, servicestack

I am making a chat client based on ServiceStack and Redis in Winforms.

I create a message collection and as soon as I subscribe to it, my application freezes unresponsive. Am I maybe missing something or is there an invocation missing. or what .....

Here is the code

```cs
 
public partial class frmChat :Form
{
```

public RedisClient redisClient = new RedisClient("192.168.111.50");
public bool registered = false;
public string channelName = "letzChat";

public frmChat()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void tbxUsername_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (tbxUsername.Text.Trim() != string.Empty && e.KeyChar == (char) Keys.Enter)
    {
        IRedisSubscription rs = redisClient.CreateSubscription();
        rs.OnSubscribe = chan => { chan_OnSubscribe(chan); };

        rs.OnUnSubscribe = chan => { chan_OnUnSubscribe(chan); };
        rs.OnMessage = (chan, msg) => { chan_OnMessage(chan, msg); };

        rs.SubscribeToChannels(channelName);
    }
}

private void chan_OnMessage(string chan, string msg)
{
    WriteLine(msg+"\n");
}

private void chan_OnUnSubscribe(string chan)
{
    registered = false;
    tbxUsername.Enabled = true;
    SendMessage(string.Format("User {0} registered to channel {1}", tbxUsername.Text, channelName));
}

private void chan_OnSubscribe(string chan)
{
    registered = true;
    tbxUsername.Enabled = false;
}

private void WriteLine(string msg)
{
    foreach (var line in msg.Split('\n'))
    {
        tbxChat.Text += line + Environment.NewLine;
    }
}

private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SendMessage();
}

private void tbxMessage_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
    {
        SendMessage();
    }
}

#region Message Sending
private void SendMessage()
{
    if (tbxMessage.Text.Trim() != string.Empty)
    {
        var m = string.Format("{0}: {1}", tbxUsername.Text, tbxMessage.Text);
        redisClient.PublishMessage(channelName, m);
        tbxMessage.Text = string.Empty;
    }
}

private void SendMessage(string msg)
{
    redisClient.PublishMessage(channelName, msg);
}
#endregion

}

Comment: On what line is it freezing? The call to `SubscribeToChannels`? Are any of your event handlers getting called at that point?

Comment: the app freezes after the "chan_OnUnSubscribe" eventhandler executes

Comment: You should update your question in that case. Your question says the application freezes *"as soon as I subscribe to it"*, but now you're saying it happens in the *Un*subscribe event handler?

Comment: Sorry, Error on my site. Its "chan_OnSubscribe". The title of the questio is still valid.

Comment: I entered the code in the eventhandlers (action-handlers) into methodinvokers and I actually get to the part of trying to publishing a message. As soon as I try to publish I am getting the following error message about which I can not find any information online  "only (P)SUBSCRIBE / (P)UNSUBSCRIBE / QUIT allowed in this context, sPort: 17208, LastCommand:"

Comment: Might it be possible that the action eventhandler bugging out the winforms gui thread?

Comment: You need to address that error message now. The documentation for `subscribe` states that *"Once the client enters the subscribed state it is not supposed to issue any other commands, except for additional SUBSCRIBE, PSUBSCRIBE, UNSUBSCRIBE and PUNSUBSCRIBE commands."* - http://redis.io/commands/subscribe Their own demo chat application - https://gist.github.com/pietern/348262 - Also shows on lines 108 and 109, two separate clients, one for subscribe, another for publish. I would suggest you need to follow that pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled upon this question because I had a similar issue and found a Solution.

Apparently the SubscribeToChannels() and SubscribeToChannelsMatching() Methods block the Thread. The following worked for me:

```
System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(x =>
{
    GetSubscription().SubscribeToChannelsMatching("__keyevent*:*");
});
```

See [Redis Pub/Sub ServiceStack, cancelling the thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21204839/redis-pub-sub-servicestack-cancelling-the-thread) for how to handle the unsubscribe.