# Redis Pub/Sub ServiceStack, cancelling the thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, redis, servicestack, publish-subscribe

This maybe a more general threading question i'm not sure.

But I've got a WPF app that subscribes to channels and listens for messages from a redis database.

```
 App.SubscriptionThread = new Thread(() =>
 {
     _redisSubscription.SubscribeToChannels("ChannelA", "ChannelB");
 });
 App.SubscriptionThread.Start();
```

Once I start this I have no idea how to stop it.

Things I've tried.

1. Using the `Thread.Abort`.  This apparently doesn't stop it, as the thread just goes into a hang then forever (no unsubscription happens).
2. Using the `_redisSubscription.UnSubscribeFromAllChannels()` from the UI thread.  This also causes the applicaiton to go into a blocking state forever
3. Forcefully shutdown using `Environment.Exit(0)`.  This one seems to do the trick.  Unfortunetly it also has the side effect of...well...shutting down my application.

How do I go about just stopping the listening, so I can connect/reconnect at will?

Am I doing it wrong by starting the SubscribeToChannels in a new thread?

Comment: I have a very similar problem. I want to unsubscribe from a channel so I used UnSubscribeFromAllChannels() but then it goes into blocking state forever and cannot execute any code after that. :(((
Im stuck on it for hours.....:(((

Comment: this did the trick. 
https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#new-managed-pubsub-server
redispubsubserver is unblocking :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example that shows how to subscribe and unsubscribe from messages is in [RedisMqServer](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Server/Messaging/Redis/RedisMqServer.cs#L321), e.g:

```
using (var subscription = redisClient.CreateSubscription())
{
    subscription.OnUnSubscribe = channel => 
        Log.Debug("OnUnSubscribe: " + channel);

    subscription.OnMessage = (channel, msg) =>
    {
        if (msg == "STOP")
        {
            Log.Debug("Stop Command Issued");
            Log.Debug("Unsubscribing from all Channels...");
            subscription.UnSubscribeFromAllChannels(); //Unblocks thread.
        }
    };

    subscription.SubscribeToChannels(QueueNames.TopicIn); //blocks thread
}
```

Where it uses a custom control message to unblock the background thread and unsubscribe from all channels from the subscription **OnMessage** handler.